# React Three FIbre Drei Bounds fill screen

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm trying to fill the screen with an image in React Three Fiber Drei.

I'm attempting to use Bounds.

```
   <Bounds fit observe clip damping={0} margin={0.75} >
      <planeBufferGeometry args={[1, 1 / aspect]} />
    </Bounds>
```

This gets mostly there but doesn't fill the whole screen. Setting the margin to 0 doesn't show the image at all.

I can't useAspect because that scales the object and I need the scale to stay the same.